# How to keep my collider from separating from my Ragdoll

Tags: unity-game-engine, ragdoll

I created a Ragdoll with all the joints.  I added a Capsule Collider.  When he falls and hits something, the collider separates and falls without the ragdoll?  The Ragdoll also has a RigidBody.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: Would you mind adding a picture of the hierarchy of the game object? I would think that if you have a collider on a parent and you're moving a child model, ragdoll, rigidbody, that the parent is not moving.

Comment: I added a picture.  The game is playing, but when I switch to Scene view, you can see my ragdoll in the middle, and the collider is falling below.